# mobile website testing localhost

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012, localhost, mobile-website

best solution for mobile website locally testing

Note: I am using windows 7 with visual studio 2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [website to mobile website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874386/website-to-mobile-website)

Comment: possibly you wrong, it is connected but question is different

Comment: http://responsivepx.com/?localhost%3A62135%2F#1236x497&scrollbars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do this is to simply hook up your mobile device to the network that your machine is on and visit the IP Address associated to the machine on your port.

Note that IIS Express is a pain to configure in this regard, so it will be good if you can setup your site to run on IIS on your primary machine, and configure it to be default website bound on either port 80 if you have nothing else, or another unique port so that the hostname is not required.

Comment: is there any other way? maybe less complicated

Comment: This is not in any way complicated, simply setup Visual Studio to use IIS, and connect your phone to the network.